# Syntax Error when inserting Values to MariaDB with Spark SQL

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, mariadb, minikube

I am experimenting with the Interaction of python Scripts with Databases in Kubernetes. I just wanted to begin with a very basic example but already struggle with an error message.

I have set up a MariaDB on Minikube and manually created a database with a table ("mitglieder"). I now want to interact from another pod, which is running a python script using pyspark. I am able to connect to the MariaDB and read the existing table. But as soon as I try to insert some values into this table I get the following error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"name","age") VALUES ('Bob',4)' at line 1.

Here is my Code:

```
spark = (SparkSession
   .builder   
   .appName("Beispiel")
   .config("spark.jars", "/app/mariadb-java-client-3.2.0.jar")
   .config("spark.sql.legacy.createHiveTableByDefault", "false") 
   .getOrCreate())

data = [('Alice', 1), ('Bob', 4)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=['name', 'age'])
table_name = 'mitglieder'
df.write.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=table_name, mode="append", properties=connection_properties)
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

I made sure that the attribute names in my python-code are the same as in the MariaDB table.

Answer (score 0):

Spark always quotes identifiers, so you have to set SQL_MODE to ANSI_QUOTES:

per session:

```
SET sql_mode="ANSI_QUOTES"
```

globally:

```
SET global sql_mode="ANSI_QUOTES"
```

Comment: Now it‘s fixed, thank you. I already had this in the Config-map of the MariaDB.yaml File but it Looks like that did not work as expected.